# Doctrine2, Symfony2 - oneToOne with multiple entities?

Tags: entity-relationship, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a user entity, and multiple profile entities. What I'm trying to do is dynamically create a oneToOne relationship based on the user role.

So picture my 3 tables:

users (core table, username, pass, role etc, used for authentication)
users_admin
users_client

Then in my User.orm.yml I have:

oneToOne:
    --profile:
      ----targetEntity: \UserBundle\Entity\Profile
      ----mappedBy: user

The problem is I need the targetEntity to either be:

AdminProfile
ClientProfile

Based on role. Is there any links or advice? I'm completely lost at where to start so appreciate any input on how I might achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want some kind of [inheritance](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

The idea being that you have an (abstract) "Profile" entity, with concrete subclasses "UserProfile" and "AdminProfile".

Then your user has a oneToOne relationship with a "Profile", which can be of either type.