# Doctrine2 OneToMany with multiple Entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, relationship, entity-relationship

I have three kinds of Users, every user has some `FiscalData` and is linked to a `UserCredential` entry.

Which translates in:

> UserX (X=1,2,3) has two FKs referring to `FiscalData` and
>   `UserCredential` tables.

Using Doctrine2, reading the docs http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html, I believe to need the **MappedSuperClass** pattern.

I have also read the following questions:

[Doctrine 2 - One-To-Many with multiple Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125184/doctrine-2-one-to-many-with-multiple-entities)

[Many-To-One with multiple target entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016444/many-to-one-with-multiple-target-entities)

[Doctrine2, Symfony2 - oneToOne with multiple entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719290/doctrine2-symfony2-onetoone-with-multiple-entities)

But in the docs is clearly stated that

> A mapped superclass cannot be an entity, it is not query-able and persistent relationships defined by a mapped superclass must be unidirectional (with an owning side only). This means that One-To-Many associations are not possible on a mapped superclass at all. Furthermore Many-To-Many associations are only possible if the mapped superclass is only used in exactly one entity at the moment. For further support of inheritance, the single or joined table inheritance features have to be used.

So, how to achieve what I'm trying to achieve, which is a **bidirectional relationship** between UserX and `FiscalData`/`UserCredential`? (so that f.e. via Doctrine I can get a UserCredential and check what kind of profiles it has associated)

Any complete *minimal code example showing how to enforce the relationship* I'm looking for (and not just the MappedSuperClass inheritance shown in the docs will be highly appreciated.

Comment: To who downvoted, please speak your mind.

Comment: As you already have noticed, the documentation suggests to use single or joined table inheritance for further support of inheritance. Are you excluding these solutions ?

Comment: You are suggesting UserX to inherit from a User base class using STI/JTI and create OtM/MtO relationships between the User base class and FiscalData/UserCredential?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The choice then between single or joined table inheritance is up to you, both should handle what you want.

Comment: It worked! I was misleaded from the answers I linked in the question. xTI works exactly as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an abstract entity instead of MappedSuperClass.  Single-table is usually the way to go unless you're sure you want class/table.

```
<?php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "mentor" = "Mentor",
 *     "protege" = "Protege"
 * })
 */
abstract class User { ... }
```